# Using Sphinx Index to do Mysql Update

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am trying to do an update of several customer/address tables so that streetnames that are stored Saint names as "St". update to "Saint". This will allow me to share ID/foreign-keys between them (they are tables from disparate sources).

I was trying to do mysql updates using a db of Saint Names but whether I do regex or Like St X or Like St Y or even just run 100s of updates (1 per Saint) updating it taking forever (especially because any 'Bla St Marys' can't be indexed).

There is not an issue finding the St X if doing a Sphinx query on any table as I've indexed that to account for them.

So my (long winded) question is is there a way, now that the tables are Sphinx Indexed so that St=Saint in the right conditions to combine my Sphinx Index with a Mysql replace?

Answer (score 0):

Well in theory you could do an UPDATE by joining with a SphinxSE table.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse

but it can be tricky to install (depending on the exact MySQL server version used)

May also have problem if using Replication, as such an update wont be replication safe.

... but frankly wonder if wil be more trouble than worth. Probably easier to optimize the updates using MySQL Full-Text indexes.

Comment: Full-Text indexes is something I'll have to look into, the tables and data are dicey enough as it is w/o introducing tricky installs and data integrity issues. For now I found a way to modify my query so that I removed the like % X' which is not indexable and slowed things down. I'll look into SphinxSE however as it seems to me to be a waste to use sphinx indexed tables vis a vis updating.